# How to fix "The handle is invalid" when closing a directoryReader?

Tags: java, lucene

I am working with Lucene 4.8.0 and I have a DirectoryReader that I can't close. When I try I get the following error :

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid
>                   at apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.reThrowUnchecked(IOUtils.java:368)
>                   at apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.notifyCoreClosedListeners(SegmentCoreReaders.java:203)
>                   at apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.decRef(SegmentCoreReaders.java:183)
>                   at apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.doClose(SegmentReader.java:258)
>                   at apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.decRef(IndexReader.java:243)
>                   at apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doClose(StandardDirectoryReader.java:364)
>                   at apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.decRef(IndexReader.java:243)
>                   at apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.close(IndexReader.java:479)

My code is as follows :

```
FSDirectory indexDir = null;
DirectoryReader dirReader = null
try{
indexDir = new SimpleFSDirectory(new File(baseDir + "/index"),null);
dirReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDir);

//operations

finally {
if (dirReader != null) {
    dirReader.close();
}
if (indexDir != null) {
    indexDir.close();
}
}
```

But this crashes at the dirReader.close(). I am new to Lucene, if I missed something well known or obvious I am sorry.

Comment: have you called writer.commit and please change the order first close the directory then close the reader

Comment: I’ll look into it.